# Solving inhomogenous ODE using "variation of constant"

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So while working through a problem I came up with the ODE:
$$T'(t)-k(65-T(t))=65-20sin((\pi/6)*t)$$
While trying to solve this I first found my homogenous solution to be:
$$T_{H}=65-ce^{-kt}$$
At this point I try to solve for my unknown function $v(t)$ (from "variation of constant" method). I know that
$$v'(t)= (65-20sin((\pi/6)*t))/(65-e^{-kt})$$
but I can't seem to integrate this (I can't find it on standard integral tables nor does wolfram alpha even give me anything useful so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong). If it is helpful k is $1/2$. I have no clue how to move forward and I have no clue where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For the homogenous equation $$T'-k(65-T)=0$$ you properly found $$T=65-ce^{-kt}$$ So, now, applying the variation of the constant, $$T'=e^{-k t} c'-k c e^{-k t}$$ and plugging in the original equation you find $$c'=65 e^{k t}-20 e^{k t} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  t}{6}\right)$$ which is not excatly what you wrote. So, integrating $$c=\frac {65}k e^{kt}-20\int e^{kt}\sin \left(\frac{\pi  t}{6}\right)\,dt+K$$ For the remaining integral, you could use integration by parts twice and get the result.

A faster method would be to consider $$I=\int e^{kt}\cos \left(\frac{\pi  t}{6}\right)\,dt$$ $$J=\int e^{kt}\sin \left(\frac{\pi  t}{6}\right)\,dt$$ which makes $$I+iJ=\int e^{kt} e^{i\frac{\pi  t}{6}}\,dt=\int e^{\left(k+\frac{i \pi }{6}\right) t}\,dt$$ (which is simple) and take the imaginary part of the result.

I am sure that you can take from here.